# Перегрузка функций в OpenGL (cannot convert)

Tags: c++, opengl, c++builder, glfw

Выпрыгивают ошибки

```
ошибка: cannot convert 'MainWindow::glfw_onKey' from type 'void (MainWindow::)(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)' to type 'GLFWkeyfun {aka void (*)(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)}'
     glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
ошибка: cannot convert 'MainWindow::glfw_onFramebufferSize' from type 'void (MainWindow::)(GLFWwindow*, int, int)' to type 'GLFWframebuffersizefun {aka void (*)(GLFWwindow*, int, int)}'
     glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);
```

Немогу понять почему  .

Вот место вызова.

```
//    GLFWkeyfun glfw_onKey = glfw_onKey();
    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
//    GLFWframebuffersizefun glfw_onFramebufferSize = glfw_onFramebufferSize();
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);
```

А вто сами функции

```
void MainWindow::glfw_onFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void MainWindow::glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

---

Если вызов тот же самый но без класса

```
 // Set the required callback functions
glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);

glClearColor(0.23f, 0.38f, 0.47f, 1.0f);

// Set the required callback functions
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);

void glfw_onFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

То всё прекрасно работает. В общем не знаю что не так (по сути даже не знаю как оформить вопрос и его название)

Comment: Не глядя в код - функции GLFW принимают в качестве параметров указатели на функции. А вы туда пытаетесь передать нестатические методы. Придется либо заменить их на статические методы, либо на обычные функции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как это сделать просто я не знаю как это написать, типа через звёздочку либо через амперсент (просто я побывал не сработало )???

Comment: Что как сделать? Говорю же, не получится нестатические методы использовать. Берите либо статические методы, либо обычные функции - это вы и так знаете, как делать.

Comment: Дело в устпойстве классов - даже если метод класса ничего не принимает на вход, то это, на самом деле, не так. Он все равно принимает по крайней мере один параметр: указатель на класс. Так что сигнатура метода и функции будет разная, несмотря на то, что вы декларировали их одинаково.